# Shared memory - shm_open causing permission denied

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I am writing a program that uses POSIX shared memory and have an error that I am unsure how to fix. I looked for similar questions but could not find any relevant to this specific problem.

Two files are involved - server.c, which contains the code run by the program, and shm.c, which contains functions that provide abstraction for handling the shared memory. This is an assignment, so I cannot deviate very far from the current structure.

Below is the relevant code from each file:

server.c

```
int shmFd;

shmFd = createSHM(SHNAME);
```

shm.c

```
int createSHM(char * shname)
{
    int fileDesc;

    fileDesc = shm_open(shname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);

    if(fileDesc == -1)
    {
        perror("Error: Could not create shared memory space");
    }

  return fileDesc;
}
```

shm.h

```
#define SHNAME "/shmserver"
```

When I attempt to run the built program in the terminal, the following error appears:

```
Error: Could not create shared memory space: Permission denied
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about giving it some non-zero `mode`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried changing the mode to S_IRWXU (stat.h is included). Also tried S_IRWXO and S_IRWXG. Still gives the same error

Comment: @bitrost: Probably becasue you ran the program at least once with a mode of 0 creating shm object you can't access that is now still there.  You need to remove it.  If you're running on Linux, try `ls /dev/shm` to see all the existing shm objects...

Comment: The file: `shm.h` seems to be ,missing the prototypes for the functions in the file `shm.c`.  The file: `server.c` seems to be missing the statement: `#include "shm.h`

Comment: after the failure of the call to: `shm_open()` and calling `perror()`, the code needs to call `shm_unlink()` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can easily determine if there are any other problems in how the shared memory is being handled.

Comment: Thanks - removing the existing object in /dev/shm solved the problem. It had not exited properly when previously run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
fileDesc = shm_open(shname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
```

gives no-one any access rights to the shared memory object. Once you create a shared memory object with no access rights, only the root user will be able to open it.

Instead, use (for example)

```
fileDesc = shm_open(shname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);
```

(You could allow other users to access the shared memory, obviously. But you need, at a minimum, to allow yourself to access it; otherwise, you won't be able to open it once you've created it.)

Perhaps worth noting that your error message is incorrect, so you might be misleading yourself (and others). The call to `shm_open` does not fail when it is *creating* the shared memory object. What fails is opening an already created shared memory object without all permissions for the user.